# How do you access the value of a DQL count() query in Java Program

Tags: java, documentum, documentum6.5, dfc

I want to get to the value I am finding using the COUNT command of DQL.Normally I enter the column name I want to access into the getInt() getString() method. What I'm supposed to do when there is no specific colomn name.

```
{
    String query = "select count(*) as count from dm_user;";
    return query;           
}
```

Code to fetch the result

```
{
    IDfCollection total = dql.execute(session, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);

    while (total.next()){
        cint = total.getInt("count");
}
```

Tomcat Result

> DfException:: THREAD: http-8080-2; MSG: [DM_QUERY_E_SYNTAX]error:  "A Parser Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of:  select count(*) as count"; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `count` which is a keyword for your column custom name, the error you posted clearly says it: `A Parser Error (syntax error)`

This will do

```
select count(*) as quantity from dm_user;
```

and fetching result like

```
IDfCollection total = dql.execute(session, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);

    while (total.next()){
        cint = total.getInt("quantity");
```

will work

Comment: you can mark answer as accepted (it seems that you don't do it on your other questions as well)

Answer (score 2):

While @Miki answered it already but I like to add one small thing here that below code should work too if you haven't specified any alias.

```
{
  IDfCollection total = dql.execute(session, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);

  while (total.next()){
    cint = total.getInt("count(*)");
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried with your way too and it also worked! 
Thank you Sanjeev!